# How to ping a Teams channel with @channel from a Flow?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I am trying to use Microsoft Flow to post a daily message to a Microsoft Teams channel that will notify the users following that channel. When I create the Flow, the message that I write along with dynamic content does not get posted to the channel correctly.

I've since figured out how to have a dynamic date with the guide here:
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-dates-and-times/

The resulting Flow still does not notify the channel when posted.
[image: Updated Flow]

Here is the resulting post in the channel from before I figured out the date issue:
[image: Results]

The message does not notify the channel.

I expect that the @channel mention would notify the channel. However, with Teams, when you type @channel, you need to pick the channel you want to mention. Is there a way to mention the channel in this way?

Comment: Do you know the name of the channel ahead of time? Or is this intended to be channel-agnostic/multi-channel? If you know the name of the channel or team you want to ping ahead of time, you can type `@<channel name here>` or `@<team name here>`

Comment: Likewise, `@general` ought to do this.

Comment: I tried typing `@Daily Chat` and `@<Daily Chat>` into the flow and neither work.  `@Daily Chat` displays exactly as it is typed but does not actually notify the team it is treated just as normal text.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify you would type @ and then the channel name without the `< >` brackets. But yes, it looks like it needs some kind of additional context to autocomplete from a 'known list', which is preventing it from being done automatically via Flow.

Comment: Currently, you can not @mention channels from bots.